# Live checkpoint with criu or docker for game applications

Tags: docker, checkpoint

I have a problem regarding live checkpointing and restoring using criu and docker.

Currently I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I want to implement a feature
to make users checkpoint their current game application states.
For example, the user can checkpoint anytime when playing the game.
However, it failed when I tried to use criu dump with the game written by sfml.

To be more specific, I used a game written in sfml and criu 2.x under ubuntu 16.04. When I start the game, I tried to use the dump functionality provided by criu as the following:

```
criu dump -D img -t 2833 --shell-job --tcp-established --ext-unix-sk --external unix[33323] --external unix[33326] --external unix[33316] --external unix[33317]
```

It seems that criu memory and file dump does not support live checkpointing some specific devices such as video card with the path: `/dev/dri/card0`.
Thus, I modified the criu source code to make it skip some part of devices
when some unsupported devices are encountered:

```
criu/parse_proc.c, line 721
```

However, an error happened when I was trying to restore with the following command:

```
criu restore -D img -t 2833 --shell-job --tcp-established --ext-unix-sk --inherit-fd fd[10]:socket:[33326] --inherit-fd fd[3]:socket:[33316] --inherit-fd fd[7]:socket:[33317] --inherit-fd fd[8]:pipe:[33323] --inherit-fd fd[9]:pipe:[33323]
```

The error message says:

> Error (criu/files.c:1477): Can't fstat inherit fd 10: Bad file
>   descriptor

I think docker also cannot handle it because it's live checkpointing mechanism is built on top of criu. 
I was wondering is there any possible way to handle it or does
anyone did such things before in docker?

Thanks

Comment: [This is a pretty broad question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Can you trim it down to a more specific, narrowed down question? Details on what exactly failed, what you modified, etc, will help.

Comment: Preferably edit your question :)

Comment: please see https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/384  and https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/436, maybe this is the reason

Comment: Thanks @Blauhirn I will check that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Docker CLI for checkpointing and restoring is much easier and less problems. 
You can try: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-checkpoint-restore-on-another-host/27427/2 and https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md

Specifically, the experimental mode in docker has to be enabled. Checkpoint:

```
sudo docker checkpoint create --checkpoint-dir=<dir-checkpoint-files> <container-ID> <checkpoint-name>
```

Restore:

```
sudo docker create --name <container-name> <container-image> 
sudo docker start --checkpoint=<checkpoint-name> --checkpoint-dir=<dir-checkpoint-files> <container-name>
```

I tried to use criu for checkpointing and restoring; however, it caused a lot of problem like your.

Comment: Thanks @ngovanmao. Did you try it with any nontrivial running processes such as firefox with youtube opening or any running game  developed using sfml or sdl2?
For another question, how long does it take to restore? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checkpointed a container with a running TCP server providing face detection services. It takes about 0.6857s, but it depends on the size of the container. My container is quite large 2.6 GB, and the total size of dump files is 354 MB. The restore time is about 0.7s (again, it depends on the size of the container). I also migrate the container to a different host with different IP address. The server is alive after migration.
I didn't try anything like firefox with youtube opening or running game as your case.

Comment: seems to be completely broken rn